# Word can't open document after adding CustomXmlPart

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I'm trying to add a customxmlPart to a docm file without success.
Apparently the file is too big (more than 10mb) to be included in the package.

If the xml file size is less than 7 mb the document can be opened successfully.

Any ideas ?

Thank you for your help.

```cs
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("doc.docm", true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;

    if (wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.CustomXmlParts != null)
    {
        wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.DeleteParts<CustomXmlPart>(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.CustomXmlParts);
    }

    CustomXmlPart myXmlPart = mainPart.AddCustomXmlPart(CustomXmlPartType.CustomXml);

    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("10mbfile.xml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        myXmlPart.FeedData(stream);
    }

    wordDoc.Package.Flush();
}
```

**EDIT : I found the issue, the xml file contains lot of carriage return + line feed. After removing them i can embed the file as a CustomXmlPart.**

Comment: Break it down into more than one Custom XML Part.

Comment: i'am thinking about this solution but the file will be used by a vsto addin, it's easier for me with one file. If it's impossible to store one unique file i'll split it in multiple files

Comment: If by file you mean Custom XML Part, I don't see that you have a choice, because the current design appears to be hitting a limit size of the Word application / document specification. (You don't explicitly say what error message is being triggered, nor what action triggers it, so we can only guess.)

Comment: There's no error message when i try opening the docm. Word is stuck on the loading screen.

Comment: @yokki There is a limitation in VBA i can't retrieve the variable, the value is truncated. Only 65535 character are returned.

Comment: Have a look at my answer below, which shows that Word does **not** have problems with very large (e.g., 30MB) custom XML parts per se. Thus, can you provide more information on what you do with that custom XML part?

Comment: I found the issue, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, the xml file contains lot of carriage return + line feed. After removing them i can embed the file as a CustomXmlPart.

Answer (score 0):

The following unit test demonstrates that you can add very large custom XML parts (up to 30MB in the example) to a Word document:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using Xunit;

namespace CodeSnippets.Tests.OpenXml.Wordprocessing
{
    public class LargeCustomXmlPartsTests
    {
        public static readonly XNamespace W = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";

        [Theory]
        [InlineData(5)]
        [InlineData(10)]
        [InlineData(15)]
        [InlineData(20)]
        [InlineData(30)]
        public void CanCreateLargeCustomXmlParts(int size)
        {
            int desiredStreamLength = size * 1024 * 1024;
            string path = $"Document_{size:D2}MB.docm";

            // Create a macro-enabled Word document with a custom XML part having
            // at least the desired size in MB.
            CreateMacroEnabledWordDocument(path, size);

            // Assert that the document does have a custom XML part with at least
            // the desired size.
            using WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, false);
            CustomXmlPart customXmlPart = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.CustomXmlParts.First();
            using Stream stream = customXmlPart.GetStream(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            Assert.True(stream.Length > desiredStreamLength);
        }

        private static void CreateMacroEnabledWordDocument(string path, int size)
        {
            const WordprocessingDocumentType type = WordprocessingDocumentType.MacroEnabledDocument;
            using WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(path, type);

            // Create a main document part with an empty document.
            MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
            WriteRootElement(mainDocumentPart,
                new XElement(W + "document",
                    new XElement(W + "body",
                        new XElement(W + "p"))));

            // Create a custom XML part with the desired size in MB.
            CustomXmlPart customXmlPart = mainDocumentPart.AddCustomXmlPart(CustomXmlPartType.CustomXml);
            WriteRootElement(customXmlPart, CreatePartRootElement(size));
        }

        private static void WriteRootElement(OpenXmlPart part, XElement partRootElement)
        {
            using Stream stream = part.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            using XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream);

            partRootElement.WriteTo(writer);
        }

        private static XElement CreatePartRootElement(int size)
        {
            var random = new Random();

            return new XElement("root",
                Enumerable.Range(0, size).Select(paragraphIndex =>
                    new XElement("p",
                        new XAttribute("i", paragraphIndex),
                        Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(runIndex =>
                            new XElement("r",
                                new XAttribute("i", runIndex),
                                new XElement("t", CreateRandomString(random)))))));
        }

        private static string CreateRandomString(Random random)
        {
            char[] value = Enumerable
                .Range(0, 930)
                .Select(i => Convert.ToChar(random.Next(33, 125)))
                .ToArray();

            return new string(value);
        }
    }
}
```

On my Windows 10 notebook, Microsoft Word for Office 365 opens the document with the **30MB** custom XML part without any problems. Therefore, I'd say, your problem must be caused by other factors or a combination of factors, including any processing of the custom XML part performed by the VSTO add-in that was mentioned in a comment.

Comment: After testing your code with my docm file, i found my xml was the problem. Thank you